# Is there a cocoa touch property pages like table view form renderer viewcontroller?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, forms, uitableview, xcode4

Is there any free or opensource property pages like form renderer for ios applications?
Or I missed something, and I can create these kind of objects with the base framework?
I want to render forms inside applications, not on the Settins menu.
Is there any built in way or any lib what do it for me or I must make the plist parseing and table cell lifecycle management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but I think what you want to do is have functionality like that available in the Settings app within your application. I have used [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) and been quite happy with the results. It's free and open source. I think they ask you to credit them, but it is not required.

Comment: I tested it, and it is a great lib. Maybe this is what I want but sometimes i need to load childpanes data over http, and dynamically create those tables, so if no other tips, I accept it as the aswer. And I upgrade the code with http functionality.

Comment: Well, even if it does not do everything you want there is still some great code in there!